# Issue installing SciPy

Tags: virtualbox, python, pip, jupyter

I am trying to install Scipy to run on Jupyter (in VirtualBox Ubuntu OS, Windows Host). I type the following command and get errors. How can I fix it?

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.17.0)
Collecting scipy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/7f/b535ec711cbcc3246abea4385d17e1b325d4c3404dd86f15fc4f3dba1dbb/scipy-1.3.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2MB)
     |▏                               | 174kB 5.9kB/s eta 1:10:27ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 507, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 447, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 491, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 911, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 313, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req, self.session, self.finder, self.require_hashes
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 194, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 465, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 316, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 551, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 253, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/hashes.py", line 80, in check_against_chunks
...
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the trace you have provided: `socket.timeout: The read operation timed out`
It looks like your internet connection is intermittent or dropping.

Is there any reason you are using `pip` instead of `conda`?

You can install scipy using `conda install -c anaconda scipy`

Comment: VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ conda
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'`